# Getting comments from a Facebook page post with Webhooks?

Tags: webhooks, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I made a small facebook webhook handler with Node.js. I'm currently subscribed via webhooks to the "page" feed. I'm able to receive posts, comments and likes made by the page itself. Also, posts from users to the page itself.

I'd like to also receive user comments those page posts. Is it possible to do this with the Webhooks feature? How do I subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, all actions on all posts on a Facebook page to which your app is subscribed will be sent to the webhook. This is irrespective of who created the post or who did the action (e.g. commenting).

This includes the following categories of Facebook page feed items:

- All posts created by the page itself
- All posts created by the page users
- All comments on page posts created by the page itself, including page owner comments and page user comments
- Comments on page posts created by the page users, including page owner comments and page user comments

Of course, as I assume you've already done, this requires you to subscribe to the **Feed** field of the **Page** object on the Facebook developer dashboard